# Does Company of Heroes CD-Key from a PC version work on a Mac?

Tags: macos, company-of-heroes

Company of Heroes has been ported to OS X.  I purchased the Windows version a while back.  Anyone know if the CD-Key will work on the mac?

Please refrain from speculating whether or not it is theoretically possible. I'm looking for someone who has actually tried it in practice.

Comment: I don't think that your key will work. I have this issue with one developer who told me to buy another copy of his game becouse of outsorcing porting his game on Mac OS X. How your story ended?

Comment: If you take a look at [Aspyr's FAQ](http://support.aspyr.com/entries/21091857-Company-of-Heroes-FAQ), they make it clear the game has some fundamental differences, including a lack of multiplayer.  Also given that CD-keys for the PC version are around in abundance, it would seem the publisher would be smarter than that.  Finally - the only way to get the game is purchasing via the Mac App Store.  How exactly would you get the game files on Mac, and not already have a key?

Answer (score 1):

The mac version of Company of Heroes is made by a company called Aspyr which earns money by porting Windows games to the Mac. They have almost no exclusive releases, just ports. If people could just buy the Windows version of one of their games and play it on the Mac, they wouldn't earn any money, so **I don't think the CD-Key from a Windows version will work on the Mac**. But it wouldn't hurt to try; I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: Huh- I visited Aspyr's website, and they call themselves 'the best Mac publisher on Earth, ever'. Maybe they do both?